# How to swipe left to delete a CollectionCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am using a UICollectionView library called VegaScroll. The library is located at https://github.com/ApplikeySolutions/VegaScroll. My question is how can I add a swipe left feature to this, so when the user swipes left, the collection cell shows the trash image and gets deleted? I know its very simple in a table, but I am using this library which is a collection view. I have searched on all the questions on this forum, but they haven't solved this problem. Something like below. I'm also using an XIB for my cell.

[image]Thanks all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a tableView existed functionality. For collectionView you should write it on your own. There is no existed pre-built solution.

You can use the pod like this (which can what do you need)

https://github.com/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit

Or custom written simple logic like here:

https://medium.com/@ales.musto/using-a-uipangesturerecognizer-to-delete-cells-in-a-uicollectionview-swift-3-e91cdfcce5be

**Update:**
There is actually a way to do this (now) with a built-in API:

[How do you support swiping to delete a row in a UICollectionView list with compositional layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64231288/how-do-you-support-swiping-to-delete-a-row-in-a-uicollectionview-list-with-compo)

Comment: THANK YOU! The custom logic works like a charm! Thanks Alex for pointing me in the right direction!