# How do you support swiping to delete a row in a UICollectionView list with compositional layout?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

Previously with table views this was done in the `UITableViewDataSource` delegate callback `tableView(_:commit:forRowAt:)`. Is there equivalent functionality in the APIs associated with [the new collection views](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/implementing_modern_collection_views), or a recommended way of implementing it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration, which you used to create the layout, has `leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationProvider` and `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationProvider` properties that are functions taking an index path. Your function can return different swipe actions, or `nil`, for different rows of the list:

```
var config = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .plain)
config.trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationProvider = { indexPath in
    let del = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") {
        [weak self] action, view, completion in
        self?.delete(at: indexPath)
        completion(true)
    }
    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [del])
}
```

Writing `delete(at:)` is left as an exercise for the reader; basically you just do the very same thing you would have done in *any* collection view.

Comment: I tried trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationProvider, it doesn't work but leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationProvider works. it's so weird. do you have any idea

Comment: @aelam The Ask Question button is at the top right of this page.

Comment: this approach only support iOS 14 and above

Comment: @JhonnyTawk That's right, the question was posed in 2020 and starts with the word "previously" and refers to the "new collection views". This is _exactly_ about what happens in iOS 14 and above.

Comment: @matt what is the approach for iOS 13?

Comment: @JhonnyTawk The Ask Question button is at the top right of this page. Or maybe just search? Swipe to delete has been dealt with here many, many times already.